# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '9788427133310_urls.csv'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to take all files in a folder, join them and put their names in their rows so I can distinguish them. However, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/unite_try.py", line 21, in <module>
    with open(file, newline='') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '9788427133310_urls.csv'
```

The file, which is the first one in the folder, is in the right folder so I don't understand why this is happening. When I print "files" they are correct.

```
folder = './urls_files'
files = []
for file in os.listdir(folder):
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        files.append(file)
with open('./urls_files/results.csv', 'w', newline='') as fw:
    cw = csv.writer(fw, delimiter=',')
    for file in files:
        with open(file, newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=','):
                row.append(file)
                cw.writerow(row)
```

Comment: `open` doesn't know what folder your file is in.

Comment: can you expand on that please? the folder is supposed to be urls_files

Comment: "The file, which is the first one in the folder" -- you're not looking in a folder at the moment, you're looking in C:/

Comment: how can I fix it?

Comment: stdlib's [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is outrageously underused, please consider checking it out

Comment: You need to use `folder` in your call to `open` to build the full path to your file.